# WinForms Custom Control Colors

Tags: c#, winforms

I am trying to customize the controls on my WinForms database application.

So far I have only tried to customize labels and buttons using the following code:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
  public class CMSLabel : Label
  {
    private Color cmsLabelBackColor = aSystem.LabelBackColor;

    public CMSLabel()
    {
        this.BackColor = cmsLabelBackColor;            
    } 

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]

    public new Color BackColor
    {
        get { return cmsLabelBackColor; }
        set { }
    }
  }

  public class CMSButton : Button
  {
    private Color cmsButtonColor = aSystem.ButtonColor;

    public CMSButton()
    {            
        base.BackColor = cmsButtonColor;
    }

    [DesignerSerializationVisibility(DesignerSerializationVisibility.Hidden)]

    public new Color BackColor
    {
        get { return cmsButtonColor; }
        set { }
    }
  }
}
```

The Button control works perfectly, but the Label controls exhibit no BackColor at all, yet I've used the same code for each control type.  Can anyone spot what I have done wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to change the "base" color:

```
public CMSLabel()
{
  base.BackColor = cmsLabelBackColor;            
}
```

Comment: PS. Any ideas how I add a different coloured border to the custom Labels?

Comment: @PJW WinForms is really bad at borders - it wants you to stick with the system stuff.  You can try overriding the OnPaint method of your label and do a simple `e.Graphics.DrawRectangle(...)` on a borderless label.

Answer (score 1):

In the CMSButton you set **base**.BackColor, but in CMSLabel you set **this**.BackColor, which has no code in the setter.